# Multiple file upload php for loop

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm working on a script that is supposed to upload multiple files. 
I'have this html structure

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="test[]" multiple="multiple">
<button type="submit">Test upload</button>
</form>
```

And this is the php upload class script I wrote.

PHP

```
<?php 

class Uploader{

public function upload($files){ 

        $this->files = count($files['name']);

        try{

                for($i = 0; $i < $this->files; $i++){

                    $this->error = $files['error'][$i];
                    $this->tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $this->name = basename($files['name'][$i]);
                    $this->size = $files['size'][$i];

                    if($this->error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                        if(is_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name)){

                            move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, "$this->path/$this->name");

                        return 'ok';

                    } else {

                        throw new Exception('Error tmp file');

                    } 

                } else {

                throw new Exception('Error');

                }
            }

    }
    catch(Exception $e){

            return $e->getMessage();

    }
}

}
?>
```

I've used the `for()` loop in past to do multiple upload task without problems, but now it will upload only one file. I've also searched here on stackoverflow and there are some peoples that discourage the use of the `foreach()` loop for the multiple files upload. Can anyone suggest me a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `return 'ok';` after `move_uploaded_file` which breaks the for loop after the first file gets uploaded.. just remove that line and it should be ok..

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I've moved the `return` after that the upload operations are all completed, and now it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

[Here's](https://www.copahost.com/blog/php-upload-multiple-files/) a great script, I found for uploading multiple files via PHP.